# Apache 2.4 Php5.4 Zend Loader

Tags: php, zend-guard, apache2.4

I've been running a development site with Apache 2.2, PHP5.2 and MySql using, in part, software obfuscated with ZendGuard (version unknown). The actual online hosting sight is discontinuing PHP5.2 forcing an upgrade to PHP5.4. I've ended up uninstalling Apache and PHP. I can get Apache 2.4 running; however, if I understand right ZendGuard requires a non thread safe version of PHP5.4. I can not figure out how to install PHP5.4 nts on my Windows pc to work with Apache2.4.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the link to the non thread safe windows pre-compiled version of PHP](http://windows.php.net/download/)

For Apache on Windows, it's recommended to use the VC11 Apache lounge build: [here](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/)

You'll need to add the following lines in Apache's httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll" #or wherever you put it
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php" #your path
```

I'm not too familiar with ZendGuard, but once you have the Apache server configured for php I'm sure it will just be a case of trivial configuration.